# Embeddable доступ к полям из hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть сущность в одном файле(внутри класс с @Embedded),в другом файле класс с @Embeddable,вопрос как с помощью criteriaBuilder создать выборку полей из двух мест,я пытаюсь вытащить поле которое сущетсвует в бд,но сам по себе находится именно в классе @Embeddable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedded сущность:

```
package com.somepackage.model;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Setter(value = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class SomeEmbeddedEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "someField", column = @Column(name = "some_column"))
    })
    private SomeEmbeddableEntity someEmbeddableField;

}
```

Embeddable сущность:

```
package com.somepackage.model;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Setter(value = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Embeddable
public class SomeEmbeddableEntity {

    private String someField;

}
```

Репозиторий:

```
package com.somepackage.dao.impl;

import com.somepackage.dao.SomeEmbeddedEntityCustomRepository;
import com.somepackage.model.SomeEmbeddableEntity_;
import com.somepackage.model.SomeEmbeddedEntity;
import com.somepackage.model.SomeEmbeddedEntity_;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class SomeEmbeddedEntityRepositoryImpl
        implements SomeEmbeddedEntityCustomRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<String> findSomeFields() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<String> cq = cb.createQuery(String.class);
        Root<SomeEmbeddedEntity> root =
                cq.from(SomeEmbeddedEntity.class);
        cq.multiselect(
                root.get(SomeEmbeddedEntity_.someEmbeddableField).get(SomeEmbeddableEntity_.someField));
        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Тест:

```
package com.somepackage;

import com.somepackage.config.SomeEmbeddedEntityConfig;
import com.somepackage.dao.SomeEmbeddedEntityRepository;
import com.somepackage.model.SomeEmbeddableEntity;
import com.somepackage.model.SomeEmbeddedEntity;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
        classes = {SomeEmbeddedEntityConfig.class},
        loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Transactional
@DirtiesContext
public class SomeEmbeddedEntityTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeEmbeddedEntityRepository someEmbeddedEntityRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        someEmbeddedEntityRepository.save(
                SomeEmbeddedEntity.builder()
                        .someEmbeddableField(
                                SomeEmbeddableEntity.builder()
                                        .someField("test")
                                        .build())
                        .build());

        List<String> someFields =
                someEmbeddedEntityRepository.findSomeFields();
        assertNotNull(someFields);
        assertEquals(1, someFields.size());
        assertEquals("test", someFields.iterator().next());
    }

}
```

Вывод:

```
Hibernate: select someembedd0_.some_column as col_0_0_ from some_table someembedd0_
```

Аналогичные обсуждения в английской версии:

- [Using an @Embeddable entity in a JPA CriteriaQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023182/using-an-embeddable-entity-in-a-jpa-criteriaquery)